# Issue with configuring proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an issue with proxy configuration. I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 648000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 648000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 648000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 6000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ https://12.123.123.12/api/$1 [L,P]
```

However, with this live I get the following error in my logs:

```
[Thu Nov 24 11:36:33.013304 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 31379] [remote mydomain.com:443] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for shared.domain:80 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Thu Nov 24 11:36:33.013325 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 31379] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for mydomain.com:443 (mydomain.com)
```

I've tried adding the following line to the file:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
```

But this resulted in the following error:

```
/.htaccess: SSLProxyEngine not allowed her
```

Any idea whats going on?

**UPDATE**

It works fine if I set connection to http instead of https:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://12.123.123.12/api/$1 [L,P]
```

However, I need to use https (certificate on 12.123.123.12 is self signed).

Comment: Cross site post on Webmasters... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101394/htaccess-results-in-an-error-on-http-to-https-change-in-proxy

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`SSLProxyEngine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine) says that you can put it only inside the main server config or in a VirtualHost.

Now, not sure if you can just enable `SSLProxyEngine` in your main server config or your VirtualHost configuration and then rewrite / proxy to upstream in HTTPS from your .htaccess, you can give it a try and in case update the question here.